# How to solve this second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation using the explicit runge kutta method

Tags: differential-equations

It its my first time using mathematica so I am very unfamiliar with the syntax. I have gathered pieces of codes to solve this system of second order non-linear Diff.Eq. :

```
NDSolve[{s''[t]== (((s[t])^2)'/(r[t]))  ,  r'[t]==( 0.611/(3700-0.0065*s[t]))}, r,s, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];
```

I had this `$RecursionLimit` error which I don't know why I have encountered. I decided to rewrite code using x(t) instead of s(t) and y(t) instead of r(t) as following:

`NDSolve[{x''[t]== (((x[t])^2)'/(y[t]))  ,  y'[t]==( 0.611/(3700-0.0065*x[t])), x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0 }, x,y, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];`

This time I got the error, NDSolve: The length of the derivative  operator Derivative[2] in x''[t] is not the same as he number of arguments.

Forgive my ignorance on using mathematica. If someone can just provide me with the proper syntax to solve this problem using the runge kutta method it will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are a few syntax errors, the correct code is like this: `NDSolve[{s''[t] == D[((s[t])^2), t]/(r[t]), 
  r'[t] == (0.611/(3700 - 0.0065*s[t]))}, {r, s}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]`. But it still doesn't work, since you did not provide the initial conditions...

Comment: Are you sure you meant to write `(x[t]^2)'`  and not `(x'[t])^2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to write precisely in Latex, the DE to avoid ambiguity:

$$
\begin{align}
s''&=\frac{(s^2)'}{r}=\frac{2 ss'}{r},\quad s(0)=s0,s'(0)=s1 \\
r'&=\frac{0.611}{(3700-0.005 s)},\quad r(0)=r0
\end{align}
$$

Now just for illustration purposes, pick any reasonable initial conditions:
$s(0)=0,s'(0)=1$ and $r(0)=2$:

```
(* set up the DE *)
 myEqn = {s''[t] == (2 s[t] s'[t])/r[t], 
      r'[t] == 0.0611/(3700 - 0.005 s[t]), s[0] == 0, s'[0] == 1, 
      r[0] == 2}

(* use NDSolveValue to compute fs(t) and fr(t) *)
    {fs, fr} = NDSolveValue[myEqn, {s, r}, {t, 0, 1},Method -> 
     "ExplicitRungeKutta"]

(* plot the results *)
    GraphicsRow[{Plot[fs[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
       PlotLabel -> Style["s(t)", 14]], 
      Plot[fr[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> All, 
       PlotLabel -> Style["r(t)", 14]]}]
```

[image]